# kubernate microk8s dashboard-proxy timed out waiting for the condition on deployments/kubernetes-dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I am having the time out issue while starting up my cluster dashboard with

```
   microk8s dashboard-proxy
```

This issue occurs again and again in my kubernate cluster. I don't really know the cause of it.

```
   error: timed out waiting for the condition on deployments/kubernetes-dashboard
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/snap/microk8s/1609/scripts/wrappers/dashboard-proxy.py", line 50, in <module>
    dashboard_proxy()
    File "/snap/microk8s/1609/scripts/wrappers/dashboard-proxy.py", line 13, in dashboard_proxy
    check_output(command)
    File "/snap/microk8s/1609/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
   File "/snap/microk8s/1609/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['microk8s.kubectl', '-n', 'kube-system', 'wait', '--timeout=240s', 'deployment', 'kubernetes-dashboard', '--for', 'condition=available']' returned  non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I am running a kubernate cluster on vagrant machines(Centos) using microk8s. This issue can be cause by many raisons. Bellow is some of them;

- Leak of memory

To fix: you need to increase memory within you vagrant machines settings
[image]

- some thing went wrong during you microk8s installation

To fix : remove microk8s and reinstall it. In my case I use snap to install it. This is how I did

```
   snap remove microk8s --purge
   snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.18/stable
```

- some time you need to kill the process and restart you vagrant machine. In my case I did

  ```
   lsof -Pi:10443 where 10443 on which my dashboard is running
   kill -9 xxxx where xxxx is the PID retrieved from the previous command
  ```

Comment: Using stable version solved my issue.